# Structuring redis keys

Tags: redis

I've never used redis before, but I've been meaning to, and it seems that my current use case is an appropriate fit.

I'm essentially trying to build a messaging app. When one user sends another a message, the data sent to the server looks like this:

```
{ from_user: 'alice', for_user: 'bob', payload: 'hello!', timestamp: 1404695488 }
```

What I would then like to be able to do is:

1. Given alice, see all users that have sent alice a message that alice has not yet read
2. Given alice and bob, return a list of all messages bob has sent alice, from which I can pop what alice has read. Once alice has read all the messages bob has sent her, then #1 won't return bob.

If I haven't clarified enough, please let me know. Additionally, another part of the reason that I've chosen redis is that since this is a messaging app, I'd like to make use of the Pub/Sub features.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to have the following data structures updated when a message is sent:

1. Unread messages: keep a sorted set for every user that stores his/her unread messages. Use the timestamp as score and concat the timestamp & payload as the member, e.g.: `ZADD unread-messages:bob:alice 1404695488 "1404695488:hello!"`
2. Senders of unread messages: keep a set for every user that stores the senders, i.e.: `SADD unread-senders:bob alice`.`

To present Bob with all users who've sent him messages that he has yet to read do `SMEMBERS unread-senders:bob`.

When Bob reads a message:

1. Remove it from the unread sorted set - `ZREM unread-messages:bob:alice "1404695488:hello!"`.
2. Check if the unread-messages key exists using `EXISTS unread-messages:bob:alice` - Redis will delete it if there aren't any messages left. If the key was deleted, remove the relevant user from the unread-senders set with: `SREM unread-senders:bob alice`.

**Note**: you'd want to perform the operations that implement adding an unread message and removing it atomically, so use MULTI/EXEC block or a Lua script for that purpose.